# Javascript/Jquery Unable to set dom element to ajax result

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I making an ajax request on a json file then running a 'for loop' that loops through the file and displays the necessary information on a webpage. The function should also be displaying the result of a second ajax request in an html element. I can console.log the result but am unable to set the result into an html element.

I've tried various different approaches like creating arrays then pushing the results, everything I have tried failed.

HTML

```html
$.getJSON("coins.json", function(result) {
      for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
        name = result[i].name;
        ticker = result[i].ticker;
        amount = result[i].amount;
        icon = result[i].icon;
        $('.coins').append("<div class='coin'><div class='cname'><img src='" + icon + "' /><h1>" + name + "</h1><p>Ticker : " + ticker + "< /
          p > < h2 > "+$.getJSON(result[i].price, function(coinPrice){ console.log(coinPrice.ticker.price); })+" < /h2></div > < /div>");
        }
      });
```

Console outputs results properly but

```
$(this).text(coinPrice.ticker.price)
```

displays

`[object Object]`

coins.json

```
[
  {
    "name": "Bitcoin",
    "ticker": "BTC",
    "amount": 0.17,
    "icon": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/atomiclabs/cryptocurrency-icons/master/128/black/btc.png",
    "price": "https://api.cryptonator.com/api/ticker/btc-aud"
  },
  {
    "name": "Ethereum",
    "ticker": "ETH",
    "amount": 59,
    "icon": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/atomiclabs/cryptocurrency-icons/master/128/black/eth.png",
    "price": "https://api.cryptonator.com/api/ticker/eth-aud"
  },
  {
    "name": "Neo",
    "ticker": "NEO",
    "amount": 88,
    "icon": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/atomiclabs/cryptocurrency-icons/master/128/black/neo.png",
    "price": "https://api.cryptonator.com/api/ticker/neo-aud"
  }
]
```

I wish to select the price object in the coins.json make an ajax request and display its value in a html element. Please help

Comment: Where does $(this).text(coinPrice.ticker.price) display [object Object]? I'm guessing in the inner $.getJSON callback.. in which case if you have an object, what's in it? (hint hint). You don't get to nest HTTP requests like that; the results are only available in the callback once the request is complete... the JQuery function doesn't just magically "await" and return the response for you..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++){
            name = result[i].name;
            ticker = result[i].ticker;
            amount = result[i].amount;
            icon = result[i].icon;
            $('.coins').append("<div class='coin'><div class='cname'><img src='"+icon+"' /><h1>"+name+"</h1><p>Ticker : "+ticker+"</p><h2 id="+ticker+"></h2></div></div>");
            $.getJSON(result[i].price, function(coinPrice){ jQuery("#"+coinPrice.ticker.base).text(coinPrice.ticker.price); console.log(coinPrice.ticker.base);});
        }
```

Hi you must modify your code as shown above. You cannot directly concatenate functions to html string.During rendering of webpage They are treated as string and [Object Object] is printed on the screen.
Passed function is executing as anonyms function inside global scope.So you cannot do $(this).Also $(this) doesn't refer to Html element inside $.getJson.
You must call your function outside html string and later assign the output as text node on desired element.
You can see i have assigned an id on h2 element , then using it to render the output of function call as text node.
Thanks

Comment: You Legend! Thank you so much. :) You made my day.

Answer (score 0):

As `console.log` has built in `JSON.stringify` you can see price as string not object when you log your attribute. 
So just change your code as `$(this).text(JSON.stringify(coinPrice.ticker.price))`.
I hope it helps.